# Efficient computation of an implicitly defined function

Tags: numerical

I have a scalar function f(u) defined implicitly as follows:

```
pow( u, -f(u) ) + pow( u, f(u) ) = u
```

The function is approximately 1, but evidently not quite so. I am scratching my head for an efficient means of numerically computing values of this function. Any suggestions?

I hope the notation is clear btw,  pow( a, b) = a^b is a raised to the power b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we write

```
 u = exp( log(u))
```

and remember that

```
 cosh( x) = (exp(x) + exp(-x))/2
```

then your equation turns into

```
 cosh( log(u)*f(u)) = u/2
```

since cosh(x) >= 1 for all real x, there can be no real solution for u<2, while for u>=2

```
f(u) = acosh( u/2) / log(u)
```

where acosh is the inverse of cosh.